# Alfresco set session variable after login

Tags: session, redirect, authentication, alfresco

I want to set some information in java session after login in share. My goal is to get this information in `C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share\site-index.jsp` and redirect the connected user to a spefic page (depending on certain information stored in session).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Below is code which can be used in webscript for dealing with session

```
HttpSession session = ServletUtil.getSession();
Object paramValue = session.getAttribute(paramName);
```

In case of jsp you can session is by default available.

Comment: Hi Kritik. My question is where can i do 
`HttpSession session = ServletUtil.getSession();
  session.setAttribute(paramName, object);`

Comment: Java backend webscript